# Custom Plugin added not showing on Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have added a custom plugin **Sample Notes**( *https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/02/sitecore-experience-commerce-extending.html* ) as in **HabitatHome Commerce** solution (*https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Commerce*) and trying see it on the Sitecore commerce but unable to.

The below steps are already done :

- I have added the reference of the Plugin to the Commerce Engine
- The config.json is pointing to correct .pfx and thumbprint
- The Host name and server name are properly provided
- The Sitecore.commerce.engine is published to the commerce sites(authoring,shops,minions,ops)
- The Update Data Template and Refresh of commerce cache is done in the Sitecore content editor.

Is there anything else I am missing out?

Comment: Have you bootstrapped your new configuration? I think that this step is missing...

Comment: What exactly I need to do? Do you mean running .\deploy-commerce-engine.ps1 -Boostrap -Initialize in powershell again?

Comment: Bootstrap from Postman just to be sure -> http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/25/setting-up-development-environment-with-postman-and-sitecore-experience-commerce-sxc-9 -> Step 6

Comment: Even after bootstrap I do not see the fields from my custom plugin showing up. Any clue what else I need to do?

Comment: Did you create the custom component and details view for the feature you want to show on the sitecore commerce and configured it in the IGetEntityViewPipeline? For Ex: If you want to extend the SellableItem, then you need to create a component with all the fields required and then a details view which extends the SellableItem. And lastly configure this view in the IGetEntityViewPipeline.

Comment: Did you try to execute Get Registered Pipelines api call from postman.. and see if you pipeline is added or not?